# How do I format each string in a list of strings in ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to write a json file with a list of ip addresses formatted as `"http://{ip_address}:{port}"` as a part of an ansible playbook.  I'm able to get `"{ip_address}:port" with the following code:

```
vars:
  config:
    addresses: "{{ groups['other']
      | map('extract', hostvars)
      | map(attribute='ansible_host')
      | product([':' ~ other_port]) | map('join')
      }}"
```

I tried using the `format` filter but it expects the input to be the format pattern not a variable to insert into a format.

If I was allowed to execute arbitrary python would express what I want as:

```
vars:
  config:
    addresses: "{{ [ f'http://{host.hostvars.ansible_host}:{port}' for host in groups['other'] }}"
```

but it's all got to be in jinja2 filters.  I feel like being able to even tack on the port number was a fluke.  Is there a way to express this in jinja?  Right now I'm looking at hard-coding the format into the hosts file.

Comment: What do you do for hosts that are not in the `other` group?  Will `addresses` simply be undefined for them?

Comment: @Jack Hosts that aren't in the `other` group simply won't be in the list.  For context, this playbook would be run on a group of hosts that aren't `other` but need the addresses of `other`.

Comment: You do not say what you are using it for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[other]
test_11 ansible_host=10.1.0.61
test_12 ansible_host=10.1.0.62
test_13 ansible_host=10.1.0.63
```

The playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    other_port: 80
    addresses: "{{ groups.other|
                   map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_host')|
                   map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', addresses_replace)|
                   list }}"
    addresses_replace: 'http://\1:{{ other_port }}'

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: addresses
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  addresses:
  - http://10.1.0.61:80
  - http://10.1.0.62:80
  - http://10.1.0.63:80
```